# Profiling cache coherence latency

Tags: c, linux, intel, cpu-cache, perf

Is there a tool that makes it possible to monitor the time spent on managing cache coherence by MESIF protocol on Skylake servers or its successors for Linux OS? I am also interested in programmatic ways in C if possible.

Comment: There are perf events like `offcore_response.demand_data_rd.l3_hit.snoop_hit_no_fwd` which might be relevant.  But those count cache-miss events, not cycles a core is stalled waiting for it.  Stalls depend on the code, how much independent work there is to do in the shadow of a cache miss.

Comment: You might want to have a look at the perf c2c command: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-c2c.1.html